# How to receive invites on Skype from Skype for Business

Tags: skype, office365

After searching the Skype Community forums I could not find an answer, but I did find [this post](http://community.skype.com/t5/Using-Skype-in-your-business/Skype-invites-not-received-by-Skype-for-Business-users/m-p/4060308#M6066), to which I replied. While I’m waiting for an answer there, which could take some time, I figured I’d post the question on the SE network as well.

I have two accounts: (1.) my work account with Skype for Business, which is installed along with Office 365 on my work Windows PC, Windows 7, and (2.) my personal Skype account, which is installed on my Mac, OS X 10.10.4. Both Skype applications are up-to-date.

Using SfB, I searched for my personal Skype account, found it, and sent an invite (at least I was told the invite was sent). But after logging on to Skype with my personal account on my Mac, I did not receive the invite.

Furthermore, despite [this unhelpful article](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12315/can-i-contact-lync-skype-for-business-users-from-skype), when using Skype to search for my work SfB account, no results were found, even with the *Allow anyone to contact me* setting selected on that account.

**Why can’t I receive an invite from Skype for Business on my Skype account? And why can’t I find my Skype for Business account on the Skype registry?**

Comment: I had issues receiving invitations from Skype for Business to my plain Skype account - they were just not coming. As soon as I updated Skype (regular one) to the latest version - the invitations arrived. But, I confirmed them and still nothing happened (the other side didn't see me). Still resolving it...

Comment: Similar: I sent my plain Skype account an invitation from O365's Skype for Business (SfB) account. Took almost 6 hours to arrive. I accepted it, and I was able to immediately send messages to my SfB account. It still hasn't seen my personal acceptance, though. Replies from SfB are not sent. ("This message wasn't sent to Mike Sherrill.") I'm an O365 admin on my business network. All external sharing is enabled at the O365 admin level.

Answer (score 2):

Skype for Business accounts are managed by your company, it is possible for them to block external communication.

https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Let-Skype-for-Business-Online-users-communicate-with-external-Skype-for-Business-or-Skype-contacts-b414873a-0059-4cd5-aea1-e5d0857dbc94

Comment: We need a troubleshooting procedure. I'm working on one, but there are a lot of hotter issues ahead of it. I'm an O365 admin in my workplace; all external sharing is enabled.